# PInvoke - Specified module could not be found. How to check for missing dependencies?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, pinvoke

I have a .Net application which relies on an unmanaged dll called Procarper.dll.  When I run this on my personal machine, the application runs perfectly fine.

When I copy this same application to my server (Windows 2008) and attempt to run it there it fails with the below error message.

The reason I'm testing with an actual application is because this initially was failing in my WCF service.

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'C:\Warper\Procarper.dll': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The PInvoke signature looks like this (I'm hardcoding the path as a test...it would typically just be relative):

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Warper\Procarper.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcr", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int CreateProcr(int width, int height, int scanWidth, int bpp, IntPtr rawData);
```

I am looking at dependencywalker but honest I don't know how to really judge what it's telling me it has been a very long time since I've had to work with C++.

Based on the above information can anyone help me determine what is failing?

I'd be happy to provide more information just please ask and I'll supply it.

Comment: I assume you've copied procarper.dll to c:\Warper on the computer with the problem?

Comment: Yes I did...thanks for asking.  I ultimately fixed the problem (as usual like 5 minutes after posting this).

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see your program searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I found the problem using DependencyWalker.  Proc Monitor is definitely a good alternative.  I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3):

So in case anyone runs into something similar, hopefully my experience can help.

Here's how I solved the problem.  (HINT: Install DependencyWalker on the machine that's giving you the problem and walk the .dll you're having problems with.  DependencyWalker will show the missing dependencies or target CPU mismatches in Red).

1. I knew the application ran on Computer A.  I knew the same application failed on Computer B.
2. The error message was "specified module could not be found".  I was focused on the actual .dll.
3. In REALITY, the error was not related to the fact that it couldn't find the .dll.  Rather, it was the fact that it couldn't find a dependency that the Procwarper.dll relied in.  In this case namely:

MSVCP120D.DLL and MSVCR120D.DLL

4. In order to determine #3, I used dependencywalker (www.dependencywalker.com).  Since I knew the .dll was 32-bit, I installed the 32-bit version of dependencywalker.
5. I loaded Procwarper.dll into dependencywalker on Computer A (the one where the application works).  Dependencywalker showed no problems.
6. I loaded dependencywalker onto Computer B (where the application fails).  DependencyWalker showed two missing dependencies (the two shown above).
7. I copied those from windows\System32 folder of Computer A to Computer B APP FOLDER
8. I reran dependencywalker.  It now showed now missing dependencies, but I still had an Error because the .dll's in System32 are 64-bit.
9. I did a quick google and found out that the SysWow64 folder holds the 32-bit versions of those System32 dll's.
10. I copied those two up to Computer B and everything worked.  Copy to APP FOLDER

Unbelievable.  Now I know why they refer to it as ".dll hell".

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You've got this wrong. You can't redist debug runtime. If you want to redist a runtime, use the installer for the runtime. If you want to copy just release build runtime DLLs put them in the app dir. Don't modify system dirs. They don't belong to you.

Comment: I didn't modify any system dirs. I copied missing assemblies from Computer A to Computer B and put them in the app dir.  In step seven i never said where i copied them to on computer B.  This is not a releasable product therefore the system dirs DO belong to me as I paid for the the computer and the operating system. ;)  Regardless i didn't modify anything. .. just copied files.  Even so...

Comment: You clearly describe copy to system32 and syswow64. And the fact that you own the computer does not allow you to copy debug rtl. You do seem to have got this wrong but perhaps you don't want to hear my advice.

Comment: David I Respectfully disagree.   I do not mention anywhere that I am copying to the system32 or syswow64 folders of the target machine.  I just state  I'm copying to the target machine.m.I never say where i copy TO.  In fact I do copy to the applications folder.   Also I don't understand your point about the rtl.  Why would i care about the rtl?  This unmanaged dll is third party.   I'm not building it.  Please carefully re-read step seven if you're truly interested in what I'm talking about.

Comment: In the interest of clarity,  I updated my answer to make it more clear  I'm copying to the app folder.  Also to be clear. ..I'm NOT redistributing this.   It's a one off application hosted wcf running on my server

Comment: You are breaking the rules of the licence. If you want debug libs you need to install VS. Whoever supplied the library has done it wrong. They need to link against release build libs. This has been covered here ad naseum.

Comment: Copying *does* mean redistributing.  You license details that these files can only be put on a computer by way of an installer (MSI)...  This resolves issue; but David is correct, you're technically violating your license.

Comment: Suggesting dependencywalker solved my problem with libRETS not working on a 32 bit box.